# How do I get environment variables to persist on IIS after running Web Deploy?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure, iis, windows-server

I have an ASP.NET Core web site that I'm deploying to a VM running IIS on Windows Server 2019.  (It's on Azure, but I don't think that that really matters here.)  There are some settings that I've configured as environment variables in the IIS Manager.  It works fine, but when I deploy a new version using Web Deploy from Visual Studio, the settings get wiped out and the site breaks until I go back into IIS Manager and set them again.  Is there a way to set IIS environment variables on the server so that the won't get erased when I deploy a new version?  I'd prefer not to use appsettings.json because I don't want the values checked into my Git repository.

Comment: You could add your appsettings.json to the .gitignore, so it wont join the Git repository.

Comment: As far as I know, the asp.net core environment variables which setting by IIS will add into the web.config file. If you publish the application, the application's web.config file will modify the IIS web.config file. In my opinion, the right solution is add the environment variables in the web.config file directly when developing.